# Bokeh plot: how to save data of a point you click on + how to update point after it has been clicked?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have a bokeh plot with a hover feature (code below). When you hover over the points, it shows you an image + some info related to the image. When I click on a point, I'd like to save this data + update the color of the point or the size of it to show that it's been "clicked". How can I do this? Thanks.

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, output_file, show

output_file("toolbar.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
    desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
    imgs=[
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake.jpg',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake2.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake3D.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake4_TheRevenge.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snakebite.jpg'
    ],
    fonts=[
        '<i>italics</i>',
        '<pre>pre</pre>',
        '<b>bold</b>',
        '<small>small</small>',
        '<del>del</del>'
    ]
))

TOOLTIPS = """
    <div>
        <div>
            <img
                src="@imgs" height="42" alt="@imgs" width="42"
                style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;"
                border="2"
            ></img>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">@desc</span>
            <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #966;">[$index]</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>@fonts{safe}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 15px;">Location</span>
            <span style="font-size: 10px; color: #696;">($x, $y)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
"""

p = figure(width=400, height=400, tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
           title="Mouse over the dots")

p.circle('x', 'y', size=20, source=source)

show(p)
```

Comment: Could you please check here: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html. As I see, you didn't do anything about what you wanted to.

Comment: What does "save this data" mean? Display it in a div outside the plot (goes away with page reload)? Write it to a file? Update a remote database? Send to to some some other REST API? Standard selection policies can change the appearance on a click, but that only lasts until something else is clicked. Are you saying you want the change to be permanent? If not, what "reset" do you want? You need to describe what you want *in much more detail* and also show some attempt at what you have tried to do to acheive it already.